# Batch audio 'watermark' adding for OSX?

Tags: batch

Hi all,

Just wondered if anyone knew of a simple bit of software that can add an audio 'watermark' ident onto an audio file easily, for OSX? Something that I can mix to a certain volume level and decide the spacing of the repeats would be useful. I think there's something for PC but not sure of anything for OSX.

Any help appreciated!
Cheers
Andy

Answer (score 1):

i believe both Sound Studio and Twisted wave will do batch stuff like that, but you'll have to check i'm away from my desk.

I like twisted wave, but sound studio is also good.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the comment. I checked out some demos and it doesn't look like they do what I want specifically :( 

Answer (score 0):

http://www.audiowatermarker.com/

With Audio Wartermarker V5, You can use audio watermarking to protect and promote any/all of your MP3 Preview files.

If you have a web site, music player or store with audio files, Audio Watermarker V5 is the tool that you need.

Audio watermarking solution is a good method for protecting MP3 files and it is also used for downloading and streaming websites.

AudioWatermarker V5 Offers Audio Watermarking solutions helping Composers, Producers, Bands, Artists and Digital Music store protect their music, get paid for their music, and distribute their music on the net. use an audio watermark on any of your music that you publish to the web. Our comprehensive and pratical software creates audiowatermarked files .More info

http://www.audiowatermarker.com/

Comment: Hi Jean. Thanks for the comment. Seems that's its only a Win application though. Anything for Mac OSX?

Comment: correct, it is a win app

have not seen any yet for mAC osx

Answer (score 0):

Nice. Thanks for remembering me again, that i´m looking for the same thing. Ic checked google and found this in one second. Does anyone tried it ?

http://audiowatermarking.info

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712254/how-to-mix-down-2-audio-file-into-one-programmatically-on-mac

First install Homebrew, then you can install ffmpeg or sox.
After that, a little shell script or automator script will help you to do the batch job.

To control the repeat interval and volume, simply add some silence to your watermark and adjust the volume.